# Info windows displaying old content

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a load of script below. When I click on the marker(s) the Info Windows display old or content from other planes. Any ideas as to the possible cause?Any help is greatly appreciated. I have looked at other ones like this on Stack overflow but cant get them to work.

```
var infoWindows = {};
var markers = {};
function getIconForPlane(value) {
    r = 255, g = 255, b = 0;
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 5,
        fillColor: 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')',
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        rotation: value.track
    };
}

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.363, 175.044),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }; 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    window.setInterval(readData, 1000);
}

function text(value) {
    return '<b>Speed: </b> ' + value.speed + ' <br><b>Flight: </b>' + value.flight 
        + ' <br><b>HEX: </b>' + value.hex + '<br><b>Altitude: </b>' + value.altitude 
        + ' <br><b>Vertical Rate: </b>' + value.vert_rate +'<br><b>Last radar contact: '
        + '</b>' + value.seen + '<b>s</b>';
    window.setInterval(text, 1000);
}

function createInfoWindow(value, marker, map) {
    iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: text(value)
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        iw.open(map, marker);
    });
    return iw;
}

function readData() {
    $.getJSON('https://crossorigin.me/http://radar1.ddns.net:3080/data/aircraft.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.aircraft, function(i, value) {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon, value.flight, value.altitude);
            if (markers[value.hex]) {
                markers[value.hex].setPosition(myLatlng);
                console.log("moving marker for " + value.hex);
                infoWindows[value.hex].setContent(text(value));
            } else {
                // create new
                markers[value.hex] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    icon: getIconForPlane(value),
                    map: map,
                    title: "Callsign: " + value.flight + ", Altitude: " + value.altitude
                });
                console.log("creating marker for " + value.hex);
                infoWindows[value.hex] = createInfoWindow(value, markers[value.hex], map)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "old content"?  BTW - It looks like the posted code (or at least the data source pointed to by it) has issues with the input data (undefined lat/lon and/or hex value). Could you please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the issue with a clear explanation of how to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `iw` variable local in your `createInfoWindow` method by changing `iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({` to `var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({`

```
function createInfoWindow(value, marker, map) {
    // added the var keyword to make the variable local and not global
    var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: text(value)
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        // without the var above the iw would point to the last infowindow 
        // and that is what would open when clicking any marker
        iw.open(map, marker);
    });
    return iw;
}
```